# How Can I Know Which "Panel" Is Visible When I Click A Button?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

[This is how the program looks like (Gifs)](https://gfycat.com/reasonablehotivorygull)

So i dont want to use tons of frames for my programs. I have many tables to show. So i made some buttons. When i click the tubbon ,it close other tables and show only one table. And when i click other button ,it  close old one and show the new one. Code looks like this:

```
btn_1.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                    table1_panel.setVisible(false);
                    table2_panel.setVisible(false);
                    table3_panel.setVisible(false);
                    table4_panel.setVisible(false);
                    table5_panel.setVisible(true);
                }
            });
```

So it close other panels and open only one panel. But i also need when i click the button "Detayları Görüntüle" , i want to open a frame with details of selected row. But when i click ,i need to know what table is visible so i can do different codes for every other tables. So i need something like this :

```
if(table5_panel.setVisible(true);){
}
```

But as you know it is not boolean so it does not works. What code i need to check which table is visible ?

Comment: 1) Start using the "Swing" tag if you want Swing developers to see your question. 2) Upload your image to this website, not a 3rd party website so the image can be displayed with your question. 3) Don't add a MouseListener to your buttons. Instead you use an `ActionListener`.

Comment: @camickr thanks for the tips i will try to do all as soon as possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a [CardLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) to contain your panels.

Then you don't need to hide/show panels. The UI does the work for you.

> i want to open a frame with details of selected row.

The button to process the table belongs on each panel, not on the menu.

The details displayed are different for each table, so the logic belongs with the panel so it can be customized for each table.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I looks like what i need.